# gccmakedep error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard

Tags: gcc, g++, g++-5

I'm trying to build my program using gcc 5 with c++11 enabled.

My makefile calls gccmakedep which then complains about missing c++11 support:

```
 error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options. #error This file requires compiler and library support \
```

I modified the line in the makefile to set the required option:

```
gccmakedep -- -std=gnu++11 -- $(SRCS)
```

It doesn't work. I get the same error. I think gccmakedep doesn't recognize the option.

How can I solve this?